# How can I call a JavaScript function from AutoIt?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, autoit

There is some HTML to pick a calendar's year that looks like this:

```
<select class="ui-datepicker-year" data-handler="selectYear" data-event="change">
...
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>2015</option>
...
</select>
```

I select an option via AutoIt like so:

```
$ret = _IEFormElementOptionSelect($tag, $sPublicationYear, 1, 'byValue', 1)
```

Where $tag is the `select` tag.

That is supposed to fire the event to update the calendar that I'm looking at but it never changes so I'm trying to programatically fire the change event some how.

I know we can call JavaScript functions from AutoIt like so:

```
$sReturn = IEEval($oIE, "myFunc(0);")

Func IEEval($o_object, $s_eval)
    Return $o_object.document.parentwindow.eval($s_eval)
EndFunc   ;==>IEEval
```

But what if I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
selectYear:function(){return t.datepicker._selectMonthYear(s,this,"Y"),!1}}
```

How can I call that function from my AutoIt script?